# OBS Not Opening

Tags: obs-studio

I am using Kubuntu 14.04, and I have recently installed OBS Studio. I recently ran it a couple of times and it came up with an error and when I closed the error, OBS shut down. I ran it some more times and it came up with an error again and when I closed it, my whole computer crashed. I turned my computer back on after charging it and it worked fine, but when I tried running OBS, it came up with this.

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
info: OBS 0.10.1 (linux)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could someone please help me get this back? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
4. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
5. sudo apt-get update
6. sudo apt-get install obs-studio

Now open File with terminal : obs studio

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling OBS:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge obs-studio
```

Then follow the instructions from https://obsproject.com/download#linux

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Let me know whether it works or not and I'll try to assist further. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried reinstalling this and it still came up with the same message as above. If you could assist some more I would appreciate it!

Comment: @andlexmine1 check if the files and directories listed in the error actually exist. You might also try uninstalling obs and then reinstall by compiling from source